# How take photo from device through iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, zooming

When I take photo from iOS app through device i want to display 3 photos like minimum zoom(2),middle zoom(4),maximum zoom(6).

Ex: I want to take photo from app. After picking photo display three photos with different zooms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`-imageWithData:scale:`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW51) method of `UIImage` class to scale the image appropriately.

Simply get the image from your `-imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` and convert it into row **data** and then you can easily pass that **data object** with the desired **scale** to the `-imageWithData:scale:` method of `UIImage` class.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma - mark Selecting Image from Camera and Library
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo (NSDictionary *)info
{
// Picking Image from Camera/ Library
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
    UIImage *img= [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    if (!img)
    {
        return;
    }
    // Adjusting Image Orientation
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    UIImage *tmp = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    UIImage *fixed = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:tmp.CGImage
                                     scale:img.scale
                               orientation:img.imageOrientation];

    img = fixed;

 }
```

Comment: i want to display images like actual zoom

Comment: i my code img.scale remain same so image like actual zoom , if you want to change scale of image return scale:(your Value)....

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
  your_image_view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(your_image_view.transform, 2.0, 2.0);
```

Comment: If i use this image has no quality.I want to display the images with quality.

Comment: Yes quality will be effected but for example if you get a picture with 100x100 but you want to show it 200x200 frame the picture quality will be bad, so what you can do is get a high resolution picture and show the zoom out image in that case quality will be same.

Comment: You cant use actual zoom(optical zoom) after getting the picture there is only digital zoom you can do.